# Is it possible to ship linux on my old samsung mobile?

Tags: mobile, java-me, embedded-linux

I have an old touch mobile phone [Samsung Corby S3653](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/GT-S3653CYAINS-techspecs), and it runs on Java right now.

I want to change the OS to some embedded linux (any thing other than what's already in it).

It is possible to change the OS? How do I go about doing it? What complications would arise if I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: No.**

First, it doesn't actually run *on* Java: it is capable of running Java apps, but as you see in the link, it says "OS: proprietary".

Second, it could - very, very, very theoretically - be possible to *create* a stripped down version of Linux on it, but you'd need to invest *a humongous lot* of programming work into it - possibly making a whole new custom port for the architecture, and then wrestling with creating *exactly* the right drivers for the device.

Third, the memory and CPU limits would also be severe - I'm certain that the current OS of the system is built to cope specifically with the exact limits of this device; that can't be said of a general-purpose OS.

In general, mobile phones are a very different animal than desktop computers: you can't just throw out one system and replace it with another, because there *is* in most cases nothing to replace it with (on smartphones, it is possible to replace one version of the OS with another version *of the same OS*, but even that is problematic).

In other words: it's very theoretically within the realm of possibility, but not worth it except for the novelty value. You'd need to spend (tens of) thousands of hours deep in the bowels of the phone's system, hunting for proprietary or nonexistent phone specs, and building your own Linux port - and even then, success is not guaranteed.

If you *really* insist, buy one of the actually shipped Linux smartphones (or Android, even - it's a fork of Linux and has various developer-friendly versions). That would be much faster, much cheaper (seriously), much easier and more likely to work.